# Vectorizing a Calculation - Bravais vector between pairs of points

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

The answer produced after vectorizing a calculation is very different from the original one, which I believe to be correct. Am I vectorizing this calculation correctly?

I'm dealing with an n-array (mean_pos) of shape (2, 91) and I was performing said calculation using for loops. Because for loops in Python are slow (and it's not the numpy way of doing stuff), I'm trying to vectorize the code.

With for loops:

```
def bravais_vector(natoms_i, mean_pos):
   b_matrix = []
   b_matrix_row = []

   lx = mean_pos[0].max() - mean_pos[0].min()
   ly = mean_pos[1].max() - mean_pos[1].min()

   for i in range(natoms_i):
       for j in range(natoms_i):

           dist_ij_x = mean_pos[0][i] - mean_pos[0][j]
           dist_ij_y = mean_pos[1][i] - mean_pos[1][j]

           if dist_ij_x > lx/2:
                dist_ij_x = -(lx - dist_ij_x)

           if dist_ij_y > ly/2:
                dist_ij_y = - (ly - dist_ij_y)

           if dist_ij_x < -lx/2:
               dist_ij_x = (lx + dist_ij_x)

           if dist_ij_y < -ly/2:
               dist_ij_y =  (ly + dist_ij_y)

           a2_opt = 2/np.sqrt(3) * dist_ij_y
           a1_opt = dist_ij_x - 0.5 * a2_opt

           b_matrix_row.append(np.array([ np.rint(a1_opt), np.rint(a2_opt) ]))

       b_matrix.append(b_matrix_row)
       b_matrix_row = []
   return np.array(b_matrix)
```

Vectorized:

```
def bravais_vector(natoms_i, mean_pos):

    b_matrix = []
    b_matrix_row = []

    lx = mean_pos[0].max() - mean_pos[0].min()
    ly = mean_pos[1].max() - mean_pos[1].min()

    mean_pos_x = np.reshape(mean_pos[0], (len(mean_pos[0]),1))
    mean_pos_y = np.reshape(mean_pos[1], (len(mean_pos[1]),1))

    tiled_mean_pos_x = np.tile(np.transpose(mean_pos_x), (len(mean_pos_x) , 1))
    tiled_mean_pos_y = np.tile(np.transpose(mean_pos_y), (len(mean_pos_y) , 1))

    dist_ij_x = mean_pos_x - tiled_mean_pos_x
    dist_ij_y = mean_pos_y - tiled_mean_pos_y

    dist_ij_x = np.where(dist_ij_x > lx/2, -(lx - dist_ij_x), dist_ij_x)
    dist_ij_y = np.where(dist_ij_y > ly/2, -(ly - dist_ij_y), dist_ij_y)

    dist_ij_x = np.where(dist_ij_x < -lx/2, lx + dist_ij_x, dist_ij_x)
    dist_ij_y = np.where(dist_ij_y < -ly/2, ly + dist_ij_y, dist_ij_y)


    a2_opt = np.rint(np.multiply(2 / (np.sqrt(3)), dist_ij_x))
    a1_opt = np.rint(dist_ij_x - np.multiply(0.5, a2_opt))

    return np.stack((a1_opt, a2_opt), axis=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful because in the vectorized version, you wrote:

```
a2_opt = np.rint(np.multiply(2 / (np.sqrt(3)), dist_ij_x))
```

instead of (according to the first version)

```
a2_opt = np.rint(np.multiply(2 / (np.sqrt(3)), dist_ij_y))
```

I hope it helps.